# Migrates between solvers

Tags: pyomo, gurobipy, mps, lp

I would like to know if there is a way to migrate the model from A to another solver.
For example, lets say i have done built my model in gurobipy and would like to migrates into pyomo. Is there a way?

Comment: You have to translate the model yourself. [Unless ChatGPT can do it for you :-).]

Comment: Pyomo is not a solver. Its a modelling framework

Comment: Nonexpert often do not distinguish between the solver and the interface.

Comment: ErlingMOSEK True. Maybe that should be clarified. @overboxed do you want to change modelling framework or solver. Pyomo would be the easy way if you want to change solver, as different solvers can just be plugged in